# Ubuntu kernel downgrade

Tags: ubuntu, apt, kernel, repository

Is there a way to downgrade Ubuntu kernel version by using apt-get package management tools? Is there Ubuntu repository with older kernel versions available?

There are HW specific reasons I need to do this. I can do all this hard way, but to keep things simple I would like to know if this can be done with above mentioned steps.

Comment: Which release & which kernel(s)?

Comment: I want a generic solution. Let's say that I'm not interested in kernel versions more than 6 months old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a PPA for that (ie you just add a line to your apt sources.list).  This lets you install any recent mainline kernel.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds